# public class final PropertyLookup

Tags: java, identifier

it points to this line and says  expected  what could be the error

```
public class final PropertyLookup {
  public static String getProperty(PageContext pageContext, String propertyFile, String key,
                                     String locale) {  
  private static Properties getProperties(String propertiesFileName,String locale) { 
}
```

and also shows enum interface expected even though braces closed properly

Comment: Note: In your class header, you can't put an access modifier after the type. Should read `public final class PropertyLookup` considering `public class final PropertyLookup` is invalid.

Comment: tank u josh could u tell how to solve class ,interface expected error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PropertyLookup Class:**

```
import java.util.Properties;

//public class final PropertyLookup
public final class PropertyLookup {
    public static String getProperty(PageContext pageContext,
            String propertyFile, String key, String locale) {
        // TODO
        return locale;

    }

    private static Properties getProperties(String propertiesFileName,
            String locale) {
        // TODO
        return null;

    }
}
```

**PageContext Interface:**

```
public interface PageContext {

}
```